# Polly decorated httpclient does not seem to perform retries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, polly

I am trying to get started with Polly.  Please see my Startup class below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services//.AddCustomMvc(Configuration)
             //.AddCustomAuthentication(Configuration)
             .AddHttpServices()
             .AddHttpClientServices(Configuration)
        .AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //This is not changed.
    }
}

static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddHttpClientServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        //register delegating handlers
        services.AddTransient<HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler>();
        services.AddTransient<HttpClientRequestIdDelegatingHandler>();
        services.AddHttpClient("extendedhandlerlifetime").SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        services.AddHttpClient<IValuesService, ValuesService>()
               .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))  //Sample. Default lifetime is 2 minutes
               .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler>()
               .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy())
               .AddPolicyHandler(GetCircuitBreakerPolicy());

        return services;
    }

    public static IServiceCollection AddHttpServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddHttpClient<IValuesService, ValuesService>()
            .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler>()
            .AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy())
            .AddPolicyHandler(GetCircuitBreakerPolicy());
        return services;
    }

 
    static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
    {
        return HttpPolicyExtensions
          .HandleTransientHttpError()
          .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
          .WaitAndRetryAsync(6, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

    }

    static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
    {
        return HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    }
}
```

I am using the `HttpClient` like this:

```
  public class ValuesService : IValuesService
        {
            private readonly HttpClient _apiClient;
    
            public ValuesService(HttpClient httpClient)
            {
                _apiClient = httpClient;
    
            }
    
            public async Task<string> GetValue()
            {
                var uri = API.Values.GetValues("http://localhost:55461/api");
                //The line below throws a SocketException
                var responseString = await _apiClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
    
                return responseString;
            }
        }
```

`GetValue()` attempts to access the Web API once and then fails.  Why does it not attempt to access the Web API multiple times as configured?

Comment: How does it fail?

Comment: @Mel Gerats, it fails to retry connecting to the service i.e. it fails once and throws an exception.

Comment: @w0051977 what do you mean by "it fails once and throws an exception"? What is the failure and the exception?

Comment: @Alex Riabov, the line I have identified throws a SocketException and the program immediately exists.  Should it not retry?

Comment: @Alex Riabov, how can I improve this question to get answers? I am struggling to get even a basic polly example working with .net core 2.1.

Comment: Are you intentionally configuring your `ValueService` HttpClient factory twice? I'm not really sure what effect that'll have on things (I see both have the retry policy but wondering if the conflict is causing unexpected behaviour). Also, given this is just a sample, any chance you could throw it on a gist or something? I'll have a crack at running it if someone doesn't answer soon.

Comment: @Smudge202, I am just trying to see how .Net Core (specifically 2.1) works with Polly.  If you can correct the sample above so it works, then I will mark the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 Polly with HttpClientFactory in .NET Core 2.1 provides syntactic sugar for creating [`PolicyHttpMessageHandler`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly/PolicyHttpMessageHandler.cs)s as [outgoing middleware](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-aspnetcore-outgoing-request-middleware-pipeline-delegatinghandlers). More refs: [Polly wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory); [Steve Gordon's blog](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-using-polly-for-transient-fault-handling).

Answer (score 1):

The policy specification

```
HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
```

handles the faults:

- `HttpRequestException`
- status codes >= 500
- status code 408

Reference: [Polly wiki on Polly-and-HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#extending-the-convenience-addtransienthttperrorpolicy-definition)

This mirrors the faults handled by the [default HttpClientFactory implementation `.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(...)` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#handle-transient-faults).

To handle `SocketException` additionally, you can extend the policies similarly to the example in [the Polly-HttpClientFactory documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#extending-the-convenience-addtransienthttperrorpolicy-definition). For example:

```
static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetRetryPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
      .HandleTransientHttpError()
      .Or<SocketException>()
      .OrResult(msg => msg.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
      .WaitAndRetryAsync(6, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

}
static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
{
    return HttpPolicyExtensions
        .HandleTransientHttpError()
        .Or<SocketException>()
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
}
```

---

(Based on comments to the original question about `SocketException` being raised and retries not occurring, this answer explains how to make the policies handle `SocketException`.)